# What is the role of DynamoDB class?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

What is the role of the `DynamoDB` class?
It exposes much less than `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder`
Am I not suppose to use `AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder` directly?
I have not found another way to get a `QueryResult` when I run a query.
This is needed for pagination.

```
this.dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain())
                .withRegion(awsRegion)
                .build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DynamoDB` class implements the [document interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKs.Interfaces.Document.html), which is a layer on top of the low-level interface (there's also the [object persistence interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.SDKs.Interfaces.Mapper.html), which is another layer on top of the low-level interface).

You create a `DynamoDB` instance around an `AmazonDynamoDB` instance.

The latter is an interface, and there are two objects that implement this interface. The first is `AmazonDynamoDBClient`, which has been deprecated in favor of the client object returned by `AmazonDynamoDBBuilder`.

However, unless you need to configure your client object, it's better to call `AmazonDynamoDBBuilder.defaultClient()`, rather than construct an instance and call `build()`.